# Why can't I ping my NAT VM yet access internet through it?

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, nat

I'm trying to understand the network configurations for VMs in Virtualbox. When I use a NAT VM, I know it can't be reached by the host or other VMs because you have to configure port forwarding. However, I can access internet from the NAT VM which to me makes no sense. How's this possible if I have not configured port forwarding?

Also with NAT, I'm guessing that even if the VM is configured as such, it only means that it is on a different subnet but if you want to route your traffic it will just use one of the available ports if PAT NAT is configured for the whole network.

Also if the NAT VM lives on a subnet of its own, how's it possible for the VM to ping the host and other bridged VMs? If the NAT VM is in a subnet of its own, shouldn't it be impossible for the VM to ping another subnet. If you look at the screenshot (left window in Windows 7 NAT VM whereas right window is Ubuntu Host) [NAT Guest IP Info and Ubuntu Host IP Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6QbC.png) attached it seems my VM lives in a completely different network than my host but why's that? What exactly is going on there?Or does NAT translate the VM's ip address into one which is in the same subnet as that of the host? If that's the case who may I find the "external" ip address for that subnet. I'm a bit confused in regards as to what NAT exactly does to the VM when it interacts with the host.

Also, this is more of a general NAT question, does inbound traffic need to have their external ip traffic converted into an internal ip address? If so would the inbound traffic have the same internal ip address as the network gateway? Or would it be assigned a completely different ip address? Is there a way to determine which internal ip address is assigned to the inbound traffic because, for example, Wireshark will always show external ip addresses.

I hope someone can help me out understanding these NAT concepts. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is the same situation like a Wifi router on a cable internet connection. All computers at home have internet access but from the internet you can not connect directly without port forwarding to a PC in the home network. NAT routers only allow traffic in one direction. Once established TCP allows communication in both directions for that connection.

Answer (score 0):

hey I'm not the smartest but i wanted to give my opinion on this. This is based on the title and some things you said and that i read, I had this issue on a VM  once i just had to open port 53. I'm not sure if this will work for you but for me it did try it out and let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi Antoine thank you very much for your reply. I really appreciate it. But I'm more interested in understanding what's going on exactly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).